# Does Laravel5 transaction work or not if I create method instead of using eloquent or query builder in my controller method

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, laravel-5

I'm so concern about my operation to used Mysql statement like update, delete, insert and within Laravel Eloquent or Query builder because I've create more Mysql statement with more conditional inside of my method in Controller so if one of that conditional or something occurs or meet any problem during I'm processing my method in controller Method I will lost my information or data my data which I want to insert or update to my database.

As below function I used **setNotification()** which I create in Notification **Model** and I have method inside that Model which I want to call it to **post_data** is a method in Controller so if I do so does DB::beginTransaction() will work or not because I prefer to keep all Mysql statement inside all method in Model.

now I currently using Laravel Transaction with Try catch

```
public function post_data() {

  if (Request::ajax() && $this->CheckPermId_from_session(90)) {

     $res = null;
     $data = Request::except(['_token']);
     $rules = [//rules varray];
     $data = [//Input data];
     $data['tranx_time'] = date("y-m-d H:m:s", time());
     $val = Validator::make($data, $rules);
     if ($val->fails()) {

           $res = ['res' => false, 'form' => false, 'data', $data];
     } else {

           DB::beginTransaction();
           try {

          //$update = Teller::where('id', '=', Request::input('teller_till_id'))->update(array('balance' => Request::input('tell_balance')));
           $updateTeller = Teller::where('id', '=', Request::input('chief_till_id'))->update(array('balance' => Request::input('last_chief_balance')));
          $insertId = DB::table('till_transaction')->insertGetId($data);
    if ($insertId && $updateTeller) {
          $this->notification->setNotification([$data['to_account'], json_encode($this->group_code), $insertId, Request::input('chief_till_id'), $data['type'], date("Y-m-d H:m:s", time()), $data['type']]);
          $res = ['res' => true, 'data', $data];
    } else {
               $res = ['res' => false, 'data', $data];
           }
           DB::commit();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           DB::rollBack();
           throw $e;
      }
    }
    return $res;
   }
  }
```

Comment: DB::transaction works well from controller in Laravel5

Comment: If I call all the msyql statement by method from Model is it work or not

Comment: Yes it will work, transaction can also work from model methods.